# What is the use of adding a null key or value to a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, null, hashmap, key

HashMap allows one null key and any number of null values. What is the use of it?

Comment: "Perhaps the problem is not that nothing is bothering us, but that we are bothering it."

Comment: In Guava, google collections, many classes don't allow null and the reasoning behind it is that 95% of the cases don't need null and they can represent bugs, potentially hard to find.

Comment: Strange thing is, that `ConcurrentHashMap` does not support null-keys, while `HashMap` does.

Comment: Only HashMap allows null :)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I'm not positive what you're asking, but if you're looking for an example of when one would want to use a null key, I use them often in maps to represent the default case (i.e. the value that should be used if a given key isn't present):

```
Map<A, B> foo;
A search;
B val = foo.containsKey(search) ? foo.get(search) : foo.get(null);
```

`HashMap` handles null keys specially (since it can't call `.hashCode()` on a null object), but null values aren't anything special, they're stored in the map like anything else

Comment: So if .hashCode() is not possible on null who decides which carriage the null key will enter?

Comment: @Pacerier There's a special method in `HashMap` (`putForNullKey`) that handles it; it stores it in table 0

Comment: @MichaelMrozek your last line
`B val = foo.containsKey(search) ? foo.get(search) : foo.get(null);`
I think we can simply call get method on search key which will have same result. 
`B val = foo.get(search);`
could you please correct me if I am getting something wrong?

Comment: @dheeraj92 Your code will set `val` to `null` if the key doesn't exist; mine sets it to whatever `null` maps to in the map. That was the point, I store a default non-null value at the `null` key in the map and use it if the actual key doesn't exist

Answer (score 28):

One example would be for modeling trees. If you are using a HashMap to represent a tree structure, where the key is the parent and the value is list of children, then the values for the `null` key would be the root nodes.

Answer (score 6):

One example of usage for `null` *values* is when using a `HashMap` as a cache for results of an expensive operation (such as a call to an external web service) which may return `null`.

Putting a `null` value in the map then allows you to distinguish between the case where the operation has not been performed for a given key (`cache.containsKey(someKey)` returns `false`), and where the operation has been performed but returned a `null` value (`cache.containsKey(someKey)` returns `true`, `cache.get(someKey)` returns `null`).

Without `null` values, you would have to either put some special value in the cache to indicate a `null` response, or simply not cache that response at all and perform the operation every time.

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far only consider the worth of have a `null` key, but the question also asks about `any number of null values`.

The benefit of storing the value `null` against a key in a HashMap is the same as in databases, etc - you can record a distinction between having a value that is empty (e.g. string ""), and not having a value at all (null).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my only-somewhat-contrived example of a case where the `null` key can be useful:

```
public class Timer {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Timer.class);
    private static final Map<String, Long> START_TIMES = new HashMap<String, Long>();

    public static synchronized void start() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (START_TIMES.containsKey(null)) {
            LOG.warn("Anonymous timer was started twice without being stopped; previous timer has run for " + (now - START_TIMES.get(null).longValue()) +"ms"); 
        }
        START_TIMES.put(null, now);
    }

    public static synchronized long stop() {
        if (! START_TIMES.containsKey(null)) {
            return 0;
        }

        return printTimer("Anonymous", START_TIMES.remove(null), System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static synchronized void start(String name) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (START_TIMES.containsKey(name)) {
            LOG.warn(name + " timer was started twice without being stopped; previous timer has run for " + (now - START_TIMES.get(name).longValue()) +"ms"); 
        }
        START_TIMES.put(name, now);
    }

    public static synchronized long stop(String name) {
        if (! START_TIMES.containsKey(name)) {
            return 0;
        }

        return printTimer(name, START_TIMES.remove(name), System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private static long printTimer(String name, long start, long end) {
        LOG.info(name + " timer ran for " + (end - start) + "ms");
        return end - start;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to stop a nonexistent timer, or one that's been stopped already, that should be an error, not ignored.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Depends on your intent.  If you want a lightweight utility that can be easily used, you generally _don't_ want to `throw Exception`'s around.  Besides, it's not like attempting to stop a non-existent or already-stopped timer is something that the caller can generally recover from.

Answer (score 1):

Another example : I use it to group Data by date.
But some data don't have date. I can group it with the header "NoDate"

Answer (score 0):

A null key can also be helpful when the map stores data for UI selections where the map key represents a bean field.

A corresponding null field value would for example be represented as "(please select)" in the UI selection.