# Using NULL as a key value in a Map

Tags: java, coding-style, dictionary, null, key

I'd like to know if using `NULL` as a key in a `Map` object is considered good style and if not what are the alternatives?

Comment: A null value is usually treated as an unintialised value. Why do you want to put it in a map?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945309/hashmap-null-key).

Comment: in what context, are you going to need the null-key ? the default value ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is generally not considered good style.**

Since `NULL` typically indicates an undetermined or unset value, it is generally confusing to use as a key to a map.  (although, there may be specific circumstances where it makes sense)

The alternatives depend on the situation, so let me use an example.  Let's say that we want color specific strings in a text, and we also want a default color for text which doesn't match any of the strings.

```
private HashMap<String,Color> stringColors;
private Color defaultColor;
```

Rather than storing the default color in the `HashMap` using a `NULL` key, put the default color in the specific variable.  This makes it really clear to anyone viewing the code exactly what this color means.

The driving factor, I would say, is if you will actually have a `NULL` value somewhere that can be directly looked up in the map.  (this doesn't happen often, in my experience)  In this specific example I gave, the default color would be used for any strings which aren't in the map.  In this case, there isn't a `NULL` string that you want the color for.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend using a Null Object (see [Null Object Pattern](http://cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/)), or some sort of default key, rather than `null` as a key. Using `null` always means you have to code to defend against `NullPointerException`, and should be avoided whenever possible.

### Edit

As an example, if you are creating an API that will allow users to add values to a map (be it a home made `Map` implementation, or a utility class that uses a map to store its data) and your first version let them use `null` as a key, you will *always* have to support `null` keys. So either your backing `Map` will have to be an implementation that accepts `null` keys, or you will have to trap suck keys, and replace them with a different key that will represent a `null` key.

As @Erick Robertson mentionned, there are cases where accepting `null` keys makes sense. However, if you are designing an API, you should really make sure that you want to handle such keys, as it always means more code to check for `null`. And it also means more defensive code for the clients of your API.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like a [DefaultedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/DefaultedMap.html) that returns a known value if the map does not contain a given key.

Depending on your use case, it might be cleaner than using (a) a `null` key, or (b) a NullObject. If you describe your actual usecase it might be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

In general null keys and null values are both poor style.

The Google Guava site has two great pages that explain the how and why of not using Null's.

[LivingWithNullHostileCollections - *How to cope with Collections that don't allow null*](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/LivingWithNullHostileCollections)

[UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained - *Guava tools to use and avoid the use of null, explained.*](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Quote:

> **But what if?**
>
> What if you find yourself wanting to put a null element into one of these null-hostile beasts?
>
> - If in a Set or as a key in a Map -- don't; it's clearer (less surprising) if you explicitly special-case null during lookup operations
> - If as a value in a Map -- leave out that entry; keep a separate Set of non-null keys (or null keys)
> - If in a List -- if the list is sparse, might you rather use a Map?
> - Consider if there is a natural "null object" that can be used. There isn't always. But sometimes.
>         example: if it's an enum, add a constant to mean whatever you're expecting null to mean here.
> - Just use a different collection implementation, for example Collections.unmodifiableList(Lists.newArrayList()) instead of ImmutableList.
> - Mask the nulls (this needs more detail)
> - Use [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's useful to store default value in map as a value of `Null` key. I don't know other cases. But it's legal so why you shouldn't if it can make some profit?

Comment: Storing Null Object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) as a value for null key  could reduce number of checks for null.