Why Stream toMap() key can't be duplicate and value can't be null
As we all know, the HashMap allows only one key to be null and when duplicated it will replace the old one. Also, there is no restriction on value.
But the API of .collect(Collectors.toMap()) in the stream is limited on both, the key can't be duplicated and the value can't be null.
If a duplicate key is for avoid conflict then why HashMap didn't have the same restrition. Also if value can't be null is to prevent something like get() trigger the NPE then why HashMap didn't restrit either.

Because nothing says that toMap returns a HashMap specifically, so why would you expect it to abide by the same rule as HashMap specifically?

That is a good one and you got me, but I am still curious why not apply the same strategy with HashMap.

A stream isn't necessarily an ordered operation. So having multiple keys it will be unclear which mapping will remain. Which version of java has Stream#toMap?

Sorry for the misunderstand, I mean the API of .collect(Collectors.toMap()), it seems since the JDK 8, I will edit the description.

If you check Collectors#toMap it say's what to do with duplicate keys. Just like when you use a hashmap, you know the last key added will provide the mapping. I dont see anything about a null value. Note that mapping a key to null is essentially removing the key from the map.

@matt the documentation doesn't say that null values are disallowed, but actually they are: https://ideone.com/Fq3soJ . Also mapping a key to null is not the same as removing the key: it all depends on the type of Map. Some maps (such as HashMap) make a distinction between a non-existent key and a key with a null value.

The Collectors.toMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v) creates exactly the HashMap, so I join the question. I found only such a workaround: var m = new HashMap<>(); Stream.of(arr).forEach(p -> m.put(p.k, p.v));

Largely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45210398/1553851

Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630963/1553851

As for the issue of uniqueness, the fact that HashMap supports key replacement isn't really an argument for the Collector doing the same. HashMap also has putIfAbsent() which will keep the first value and discard the second. Who's to say which is more correct in the general case?

@shmosel your first "dupe" is not related, as it asks about Map.of which was introduced in Java 9 and returns a different type of map than HashMap whereas this question is about a feature that existed in Java 8 and returns an actual HashMap in most implementations. However, Nicolai Parlog's answer to that question contains very useful information relevant to this question.

@k314159 I said it's largely a dupe, because the principle is the same.

@KonstantinMakarov The documentation for toMap() says that there is no guarantee about the type of map returned, although they added that post Java 8.

In most JDKs, including Oracle's and OpenJDK, the Collectors.toMap method disallows duplicates, null keys and null values because it can! Weird as it may seem, this is actually an advantage.
First of all, let's see what the documentation says. Collectors.toMap says "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned."
So we can only assume the returned map is some kind of class that implements the Map interface. And in turn the documentation for Map says "some implementations prohibit null keys and values". Therefore, Collectors.toMap() can indeed prohibit null values.
But wait: in the OpenJDK and Oracle implementations, we can see that Collectors.toMap() in fact returns a HashMap, and the HashMap class is clearly documented to allow null keys and values. So why doesn't toMap() allow them?
Imagine if it did, and you write a program that appears to work well for years, and then you give it to a colleague or client, and they run it using a different vendor's JDK. Then it crashes, because your application actually wasn't well-behaved, but you didn't know it. By disallowing null keys and values, this implementation is doing you a favour.

It sounds solid, and seems like HashMap has some flaw design but it's too late to change without modifying the old code.

The HashMap has nothing to do with it. It's all about the toMap collector.

@KonstantinMakarov this is indeed about the toMap collector and not HashMap, but in fact there is a large body of opinion that the original designers of HashMap had made a mistake in allowing it to support null values, and that it ought to work the way "modern" maps like Map.of() do.

As in other comment to Konstantin Makarov, toMap permits keys to be null - see System.out.println(Stream.of(new String[]{null, "a"}).collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, v->"value:"+v)));

@DuncG good point. It does indeed permit null keys (but not null values). But I wouldn't rely on it, in case some future implementation changes the map type to one that doesn't allow null keys (even though that will probably never happen).

@DuncG, I understood from the text of the question that we are talking about null values, not null keys.

For the toMap collector:

Duplicate keys are allowed when implementing the mergeFunction
Null for values are prohibited, otherwise they would conflict with the entry removal functionality

The toMap collector containing BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction calls the map.merge function, to which BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction is also passed:
BiConsumer<M, T> accumulator = (map, element) -> map.merge(
    keyMapper.apply(element),
    valueMapper.apply(element),
    mergeFunction);                   // <---

The merge function looks like this:
default V merge(K key, V value,
        BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V>
            remappingFunction) {      // mergeFunction
    Objects.requireNonNull(remappingFunction);
    Objects.requireNonNull(value);    // <---
    V oldValue = get(key);
    V newValue = (oldValue == null)
        ? value
        : remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
    if (newValue == null) {
        remove(key);                  // <---
    } else {
        put(key, newValue);
    }
    return newValue;
}

That is, the mergeFunction allows you not only to choose between the old and new values for the same keys, but also to delete the entry completely.
For example:
class Pair {
    final String k, v;
    public Pair(String k, String v) { this.k = k; this.v = v; }
}

final var arr = new Pair[]{
    new Pair("A", "val_1"),
    new Pair("B", "val_2"),
    new Pair("A", "val_3"),
};

System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors
    .toMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v, (v1, v2) -> v1)));       // {A=val_1, B=val_2}
System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors
    .toMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v, (v1, v2) -> v2)));       // {A=val_3, B=val_2}
System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors
    .toMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2)));  // {A=val_1val_3, B=val_2}
System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors
    .toMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v, (v1, v2) -> null)));     // {B=val_2}


What should I do if I don't need such toMap collector functionality?
You can use your own collector:
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, V>> toHashMap(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
    Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        list -> {
            var map = new HashMap<K, V>();
            list.forEach(element ->
                map.put(
                    keyMapper.apply(element),
                    valueMapper.apply(element)));
            return map;
        });
}

System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(toHashMap(p -> p.k, p -> p.v)));


Point 2. isn't true (or perhaps not for all JDK), toMap collector permits null keys at least in JDK14/17/21/22. See System.out.println(Stream.of(new String[]{null, "a"}).collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, v->"value:"+v)));

@DuncG, In the 1st point, I meant the keys. In the 2nd point, I meant the values.
